# Does a brit milah require the se'udah to be on the same day?

Tags: brit-milah, meal-seudah

Suppose that an infant is healthy enough to have his brit (circumcision) on the eight day, but the doctor recommends that infant should not be exposed to a large crowd. So, they have the brit in the infant's home.

Can they make the se'udah on a different day or on the same day but at a different place and would that be considered a *se'udat brit* / *se'udat mitzvah*?

If they can make it on a different day, is there any time limit? (e.g. mom is still hospitalized and it may take 3 months for recovery, and she wants to be part of her own son's simcha.)

Or does that occur only when the se'udah is in the same place as the brit and immediately following it?

Comment: On a fast day the brit takes place in the morning but the meal is held at night following the end of the fast.

Comment: @JoelK Holy "cut" to the chase, man! I think you pretty much answered it. Now, if we can determine if this is a general rule that allows separating, or a fats day is the only time we can do this because we have to.

Comment: Is your specific example relevant to the question? If so, please explain why. It seems they could easily just have the meal without the baby present.

Comment: @Daniel I edited. The examples are not specific. I'm asking generally if it can be done on a different day and if there is any time limit.

Comment: When I made a brit mila in the afternoon, I was told it was better to at least start the seuda on the day of the brit rather than brit before shkia and seuda after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Shulchan Aruch Yoreh De’ah 265:12](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.265.12?lang=he) writes that the custom is to make the celebratory meal **on the day of the *brit*.**

The implication is that the meal need not immediately follow the *brit*, but should be on the same day. (Rav Aviner [here](http://shlomo-aviner.net/index.php?title=%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94_(%D7%A9%D7%95%22%D7%AA)) understands Shulchan Aruch similarly.)

[Pitchei Teshuvah ad loc.](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pithei_Teshuva_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.265.16?lang=he) writes that if for whatever reason the meal was not held on the day of the *brit*, it should be held on another day.

Comment: Thanks. I have trouble accessing the links, now. If you notice anything that states a time limit for the Se'udah, please edit that. I would assume that there needs to be a "reasonable" limit. I can't imagine someone who didn't have a brit se'udah says he wants to do it during his *sheva brachot*.